# Showing a HTML page inside SSRS report

Tags: html, sql, reporting-services, report, embedding

I have a html file with some images in a directory. I would simply want to open a report and show the html file (including the images) inside the report. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For the robot conversion, I think the HTML and CSS has to be cleaned with brackets everywhere and code like http://openweb.eu.org/articles/tableaux_css : `table {border: medium solid #000000;} td, th {border: thin solid #6495ed;}`! ;oP

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over the html which is produced. It is produced by another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is what resolved the issue.  I am converting the html to a image using CutyCapt and storing the image in the database as a blob.  In the report I have a image control which refers to the image and this works fine.

Hope this helps.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

I've found this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207057.aspx. Tell me if it's useful? ;oP

*To add HTML from a field in your dataset into a text box*

*1.On the Insert tab, click List. Click the design surface, and then drag to create a box that is the size you want.
The Dataset Properties dialog box opens. You can use a shared dataset or a dataset embedded in your report. For more information, click Dataset Properties Dialog Box, Query (Report Builder) or Dataset Properties Dialog Box, Query.*

*2.On the Insert tab, click Text Box. Click in the list, and then drag to create a box that is the size you want.*

*3.Drag an HTML field from your dataset into the text box. A placeholder is created for your field.*

*4.Right-click the placeholder, and then click Placeholder Properties.*

*5.On the General tab, verify that the Value box contains an expression that evaluates to the field you dropped in step 3.*

*6.Click HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles. This causes the field to be evaluated as HTML.*

*7.Click OK.*

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for looking into this. It is a very useful link, however I do not have a dataset. All I have is an html file and bunch of images for the html page. I can open the html file in the browser and it works fine. What I want is to open a report and the html file should be displayed.

Comment: The link has come handy when I setup a dataset. I can see the html file when I open the report. However the tables from the html file is not drawn only text is shown.  Any ideas???

Comment: That could depends on the way you drawn it with css or not, which level of CSS, could you have a piece of HTLM/CSS code of this table?

Comment: <p><h4>b</h4>
<table width="100%" border="1"><tr>
<td align="LEFT" nowrap><b><i>b</i></b></td>
<td align="CENTER" nowrap><b><i>b</i></b></td>
<td align="CENTER" nowrap><b><i>b</i></b></td>
<td align="CENTER" nowrap><b><i>b</i></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT"><b>b</b></td>
<td align=center style=color:black>b</td><td align=center style=color:black>b</td><td align=center style=color:black>b</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT"><b>b</b></td>
<td align=center style=color:black>b</td><td align=center style=color:black>b</td><td align=center style=color:black>b</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: Thanks once again to everyone for looking into this. I found that reporting services 2008 cannot interpret table tags. Any other ideas please.